Can't make Invoke-Expression collect errors without redirection
Invoke-Expression "git clone asdasdasd" -ErrorVariable myErrors doesn't store any errors in the $myErrors variable.  It displays it on the screen.
Invoke-Expression "git clone asdasdasd" -ErrorVariable myErrors 2>file.txt stores the errors in file.txt and also in the $myErrors variable.
I don't understand why the errors are only captured in the variable if the error stream is redirected.
(This is on PowerShell 5.1 on Windows)

Are you missing a dollar sign before the variable name myErrors?  Should be $myErrors.

@jdweng: No, it shouldn't be $myErrors, because -ErrorVariable parameter expects the name of a variable, not its value - hence myErrors.


You're calling an external (native) application, git.
By design, PowerShell does not route an external application process' stderr stream via PowerShell's loosely analogous error output stream by default, because the latter is only for true (PowerShell) errors, whereas stderr lines cannot be assumed to be errors, given that the stderr stream is in essence used for all non-data output, including status messages, for instance; stderr output is therefore passed through to the console (terminal) by default (and so is stdout output).
Therefore, -ErrorVariable in isolation isn't capable of collecting stderr output.

Windows PowerShell solution:
However, as an opt-in you can apply a 2> redirection to an external-application call in order to route stderr lines through PowerShell's error stream, but only in Windows PowerShell, not also in PowerShell (Core) 7 (see next section).
This rerouting has the following ramifications:

Stderr lines are then collected in the automatic $Error variable, which is a session-wide log of all errors.

With Invoke-Command and Invoke-Expression, you can collect them in a call-specific variable using the common -ErrorVariable parameter, as you've attempted.


Note that stderr lines routed via PowerShell's error stream are wrapped in [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] instances with a .FullyQualifiedErrorId property value of NativeCommandError; as a result, they render like PowerShell errors when printed to the screen; to extract just the original text, call .ToString() on them.
Given that Invoke-Expression (iex) should generally be avoided, it's better to use Invoke-Command in your case; note that you can use $null as the 2> redirection target if all you care about is collecting the stderr output in a variable:
# !! Works in *Windows PowerShell* only.
# 2>$null is necessary in order for -ErrorVariable to work.
Invoke-Command { git clone asdasdasd } 2>$null -ErrorVariable myErrors


PowerShell (Core) 7 / cross-edition solution:
Note: This solution works in Windows PowerShell too, so you can use it in cross-edition code.
In PowerShell 7, 2> redirections no longer route stderr output through PowerShell's error stream, because it arguably should never have been, given that it cannot assumed to represent errors.
As an alternative, you can use a 2>&1 redirection and process both stdout and stderr output via PowerShell's success output stream.
Since the wrapping of stderr lines in [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] instances still applies, you can use the data type of each object in the success stream to distinguish between stdout and stderr lines, via the -is operator:
# Works in both PowerShell editions.

$stdErrLines = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

git clone asdasdasd 2>&1 |
  ForEach-Object { 
   if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) { $stdErrLines.Add($_) }
   else { $_ } # stdout line, pass it through
  }

For a variation of this approach that collects both stdout and stderr, in separate collections, see this answer.

Potential future enhancement (PowerShell 7.5 at the earliest, if ever):
An experimental feature named PSRedirectToVariable, available since preview 4 of v7.5, now allows variables to be redirection targets, using variable:<varname> syntax.
This would simplify the solution as follows:
# !! PowerShell *7.5 preview 4 or above only*, with 
# !! experimental feature PSRedirectToVariable enabled.
git clone asdasdasd 2> variable:myErrors

Caveat: As with any experimental feature,

it must be enabled, with Enable-ExperimentalFeature (though in preview versions of PowerShell all experimental features are enabled by default).

it isn't guaranteed to become a stable (official) feature; feedback from the community and presumably usage information based on telemetry factor into the decision.



Thank you on both counts.  In this case, it's the non-data output I want to collect, so it looks like I need to do the redirection to trigger the values to end up in the variable I want.
(And I'll switch to Invoke-Expression)

My pleasure, @AndrewDucker; yes (though I assume you meant switching to Invoke-Command). Please also see my update, which added a PowerSell 7 / cross-edition solution, as well as a potential future enhancement that would allow you to capture stderr output directly in a variable with a redirection.

You assume correctly, and thank you that's stunningly complete!
